# go fyne linux проблемы с компиляцией

Tags: linux, golang, bash, debian

При установке:

```
sudo apt-get install golang gcc libgl1-mesa-dev xorg-dev
```

пишет:

```
Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 libc6-dev : Зависит: libc6 (= 2.31-13+deb11u5) но 2.35-3 должен быть установлен
             Зависит: libc-dev-bin (= 2.31-13+deb11u5)
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки: у вас зафиксированы сломанные пакеты.
```

Не понимаю что делать дальше.

```
libc6:
  Установлен: 2.35-3
  Кандидат:   2.35-3
  Таблица версий:
 *** 2.35-3 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.31-13+deb11u5 500

libc6-dev:
  Установлен: (отсутствует)
  Кандидат:   2.31-13+deb11u5
  Таблица версий:
     2.31-13+deb11u5 500
```

Пробовал и удалять и переустанавливать, ничего не помогает.
Где-то косяк в пакетах, как понять где?

Как я уже понял, косяк в версиях.
Нужно либо понизить версию libc6, либо как-то обновить libc6-dev.

Что пробовал:

```
sudo apt install -f 

sudo apt install -t bullseye-backports libc6

sudo apt install -t bullseye-backports libc6-dev

sudo apt install -t bullseye-backports xorg-dev

sudo apt install libc6-dev=2.31-13+deb11u5

sudo apt install libc6-dev=2.35-3

sudo apt install -t bullseye-backports libc6-dev=2.35-3

sudo apt install libc6-dev=2.35-3

sudo apt install libc6=2.31-13+deb11u5

sudo apt install -t bullseye-backports libc6=2.31-13+deb11u5

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: ```sudo apt upgrade``` делался?)

Comment: да. дополнил в описании то что пробовал.

Comment: Вы можете попробовать использовать команду `apt-get` с параметром `--reinstall`, чтобы принудительно переустановить пакет `libc6-dev` вместе с любым другим пакетом, вызывающим проблемы.

Comment: --reinstall тоже пробовал

Comment: Я бы начал с `apt-cache policy libc6` чтобы понять, не стоит ли какой-нибудь пин на `libc6`. Но вообще этот вопрос никак не связан с Go; его лучше задать в [профильных местах](https://www.debian.org/international/Russian.ru.html), не на SO, потому что вопрос явно потребует _обмена_ информацией, для чего SO непригоден. Список рассылки `debian-russian` вполне подойдёт.